# "nl80211 driver initialization failed." by hostapd

Tags: wifi

I am trying to create an access point with rt5370.

I created the rt5370ap.ko file.
It seemed that the driver loading is done.

*/ # insmod lib/modules/rt5370ap.ko

[   47.130742] rtusb init rt2870 --->

[   47.135017]

[   47.135023]

[   47.135028] === pAd = d0b36000, size = 519248 ===

[   47.135037]

[   47.151965] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0

[   47.157020] Efuse Size=0x2d [2d0-2fc]

[   47.160978] NVM is EFUSE

[   47.163635] 80211> RFICType = 3

[   47.166928] 80211> Number of channel = 44

[   47.174209] 80211> Number of rate = 12

[   47.178001] 80211> CurTxPower = 0 dBm

[   47.187834] 80211> TxStream = 0

[   47.197954] crda> requlation requestion by core: 00

[   47.205118] 80211> CFG80211_Register

[   47.223668] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870*



And I exected the hostapd.
This is my hostapd.conf

*interface=ra0

driver=nl80211

ssid=test

hw_mode=g

channel=6

macaddr_acl=0*



But the daemon is stoped.

/ # hostapd -d etc/hostapd-test.conf &
*random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random

Configuration file: etc/hostapd-test.conf

nl80211: Could not add multicast membership for vendor events: -2 (No such file or directory)

rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device

nl80211: RFKILL status not available

nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1

nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5

nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2

nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4

nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX

nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands

nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0

netlink: Operstate: ifindex=2 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)

nl80211: Set mode ifindex 2 iftype 2 (STATION)

nl80211: Failed to set interface 2 to mode 2: -95 (Operation not supported)

nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down

nl80211: Set mode ifindex 2 iftype 2 (STATION)

nl80211: Failed to set interface 2 to mode 2: -95 (Operation not supported)

[  702.490286] NICLoadFirmware: We need to load firmware

[  702.845068] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0

[  702.850341] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b4e73c!

[  702.858264] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b4e86c!

[  702.863658] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b37a10!

[  702.875068] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b38868!

[  702.883621] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b396c0!

[  702.888809] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b3a518!

[  702.893892] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b3b370!

[  702.899201] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b3c1c8!

[  702.906843] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b3d020!

[  702.912062] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b3de78!

[  702.917028] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b45c50!

[  702.922430] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj d0b46524!

[  702.931594] -->RTUSBVenderReset

[  702.941120] <--RTUSBVenderReset

[  703.648085] 1. Phy Mode = 0

[  703.650955] 2. Phy Mode = 0

[  703.653652] NVM is Efuse and its size =2d[2d0-2fc]

[  703.773057] 3. Phy Mode = 0

[  703.778510] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1

[  703.778522] NICInitRT5390RFRegisters: Initialize frequency - EEPROM = 44, RF_R17 = 0

[  703.839126] AsicSetRxAnt, switch to main antenna

[  703.872634] bAutoTxAgcG = 0

[  703.875409] MCS Set = 00 00 00 00 00

[  703.926320] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0

[  703.939260] 80211> re-init bands...

[  703.942774] 80211> re-init bands...

[  703.950067] 80211> RFICType = 1

[  703.953036] 80211> Number of channel = 44

[  703.957152] 80211> Number of rate = 12

[  703.960986] 80211> CurTxPower = 0 dBm

[  703.964549] 80211> TxStream = 1

[  703.967772] crda> CFG80211_RegRuleApply ==>

[  703.974549] crda> reset chan/power for 2.4GHz

[  703.978777] Chan 001:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  703.983724] Chan 002:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  703.988647] Chan 003:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  703.993614] Chan 004:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  703.998499] Chan 005:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.003482] Chan 006:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.008380] Chan 007:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.013343] Chan 008:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.018279] Chan 009:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.023223] Chan 010:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.028140] Chan 011:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.033113] Chan 012:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.038038] Chan 013:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.042984] Chan 014:        power 0 dBm, DFS 0, DFS Type 0

[  704.064110] crda> Number of channels = 14

[  704.073904] 0x1300 = 00073200

nl80211: Interface mode change to 2 from 0 failed

nl80211 driver initialization failed.

hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x90280)

hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1

hostapd_interface_deinit(0x90280)

hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss ra0

hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x90dd0 (ra0))

hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface ra0 wasn't started

hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit

hostapd_interface_free(0x90280)

hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x90dd0

hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x90280)

hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x90280)

hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x90280*



Is it a problem to not be able to change modes?
Then, should I modify the hostapd source code?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, the usual way is `hostapd` (there are plenty of tutorials, google). What other way would you want, and why would you prefer another way?

Comment: Actually, I don't know about a network. And on my embedded board, The hostapd occurred error.<br> So, I wrote to ask for advice.<br>

Comment: Please edit the question and describe exactly how you started hostapd, what configuration file you used, and what the error was. Use four spaces to indent copy-pasted output from your terminal (error codes, your configuration file(s)), so it gets properly formatted on stackexchange.

Comment: This problem was associated "nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands". Refer to this link "http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2013-January/027113.html".